# owner-draw tab control - text of a tab item

Tags: c, winapi

I am trying to do owner-draw tab control. In DRAWITEMSTRUCT structure, I get some information about a tab item that is being drawn, like its rectangle, hDC, hwnd, but I can't not find its text which is given when it is created (LPTSTR pszText member of the LPTSTR TCITEM structure).

How to get the text of a tab item when one wants to do owner-draw?

Comment: Have you tried GetWindowText using hwnd?

Comment: But what I need is the text of a tab item, and a tab item doesn't have a hwnd. It is the tab control has its hwnd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The universal way is documented in the [SDK article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760550%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#owner_drawn_tabs) for tab controls:

> By default, the itemData member of DRAWITEMSTRUCT contains the value of the lParam member of the TCITEM structure. However, if you change the amount of application-defined data per tab, itemData contains the address of the data instead. You can change the amount of application-defined data per tab by using the TCM_SETITEMEXTRA message.

So you can always hang a pointer on the TCITEMs you add and get it back through itemData.  Which is enough to get *any* info back about the tab, including data that you maintain yourself.

Not actually necessary if you only need the text.  You can simply use TCM_GETITEM to get a TCITEM back.  Pass DRAWITEMSTRUCT.itemID.